# C++ VCPKG Build All Failed - blocked by group policy

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, vcpkg

I'm trying to learn how to use vcpkg for C++ using Microsoft Visual Studio. I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/get_started/get-started-vs?pivots=shell-cmd) tutorial, and I'm up to the building the project step, and I'm getting this error:

> Build All started: Project: VCPKG Test, Configuration: default ------
> This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.
>
> Build All failed.

I have tried a bunch of tutorials for disabling group policy, if this is the error, but there is no group policy enforced on my computer, as far as I can tell. My laptop is part of my school domain, but I don't believe that should impact MSVC.
This is the code:

```
// CmakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)

project ("VCPKG Test")

find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable (VCPKGTEST "VCPKG Test.cpp")

target_link_libraries(VCPKGTEST PRIVATE fmt::fmt)
```

```
// Main.cpp

#include <fmt/core.h>

int main()
{
    fmt::print("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

```
// CMakeUsersPresets.json

{
  "version": 3,
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "C:/Users/NOR0029/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: > "My laptop is part of my school domain"  -- if this PC is running management software installed by your school then it might be applying a group policy.  If you are doing this work for a class, you might let your instructor know about the error.

Comment: @DaveS Turns out I literally just had to run MSVC as administrator, thanks for your suggestion